# Работа с несколькими базами данных

Tags: база-данных

У меня выводятся последние заметки на сайте, но только с одной БД. Как сделать так, чтобы выводились заметки, например, из 2-ух БД. Сайт самописный.

Comment: В общем случае - добавить строку подключения ко второй базе и использовать её. Скажите, пожалуйста, какую БД, окружение/язык вы используете?

Answer (score 1):

Сначала подключайтесь к 1-ой БД и выводите заметки. Потом закрывайте соединение с 1-ой БД и подключайтесь ко 2-ой. Выводите заметки и отключайтесь.